# I got error like NameError: name 'df_clean' is not defined

Tags: python-3.5

Counting Handset Manufacturers

```
top3 = df_clean.info()['Handset Manufacturer'].value_counts().head(3)
```

top3

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

2 problems: One problem is that you need to define what data the `df_clean` variable should point to, like:

```
import pandas as pd

df_clean = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df_clean.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      int64
 1   B       3 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes
```

The other problem is that the `pandas.DataFrame.info` method returns `None`, so there is no way you can subscript from `df_clean.info()` *(like the `df_clean.info()['Handset Manufacturer']` you did in your code)*. Try removing the `.info()` part, like:

```
top3 = df_clean['A'].value_counts().head(3)
print(top3)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```